# How many exchanges have delisted ETH as a result of the proposed post DAO hack Ethereum hardfork?

Tags: the-dao, exchanges, hardforks

So far I am only aware of the [Cryptopia](https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Exchange/?market=ETH_BTC) announcement below. Have any other exchanges delisted of threatened to delist ETH yet? If so, which exchanges and how many?

> ETH / BTC market is closing
>
> Cryptopia believes in immutable blockchain technology, We believe that
>   ETH forking their network to save the failures of a 3rd party software
>   developer sets a dangerous precedent as this will open the floodgates
>   to rollbacks for any other potential fund loss of ETH, Had this been
>   the fault of the ETH network core itself this would not be an issue,
>   but since DAO has nothing to do with the ETH network this action seems
>   to be totally motivated my money and investor pressure, with all this
>   in mind Cryptopia have decided to remove ETH from the site to avoid
>   the upcoming fork and any inevitable future forks to save ICO
>   investors., Please close all open orders and withdraw your ETH BEFORE
>   the hardfork is implemented as we WILL NOT be upgrading to the new
>   hardfork, Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the long list of Ethereum exchanges found here: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/#markets

Cryptopia appears to be the only one that has announced that it will remove Ethereum

Cryptopia Ethereum trading volume is extremely small (less than 1 BTC in ETH/BTC trading volume for the last 24 hours). Therefore the global liquidity impact of ETH being delisted from just that exchange is minuscule.